# pandas filter/combine similar string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains Names, and I am trying to combine similar names. Example:

```
| name      | foo_val |
| --------- | ------- |
| Andrew    | 2       |
| Braden    | 1       |
| Cheryl    | 4       |
| Cheryl :D | 1       |
| Christian | 1       |
| Derrick   | 2       |
| Derrick L | 2       |
```

...

etc... where I would want to merge the row (and the value of foo_val)if the content is similar enough (such as Cheryl and Derrick in the above example), so it would look like the following:

```
| name      | foo_val |
| --------- | ------- |
| Andrew    | 2       |
| Braden    | 1       |
| Cheryl    | 5       |
| Christian | 1       |
| Derrick   | 4       |
```

I don't know Pandas as well as I'd like to yet, but I have looked at `duplicated` ( as in `df.duplicated('name')`) and `groupby` as well as `merge` but i'm pretty sure that these are NOT what I want (very well may be wrong...). On that note, I searched around for this a lot, but assume that this has been asked before, so please point out alternate questions/answers if I missed them...

I could imagine a way to do this in pure Python with iteration, but would love to find out if this is possible in Pandas...

Comment: The real trick to this question is defining what counts as a similar name.

Comment: yeah i get that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have posted, you need to groupby the first part of the string and combine the result. That can be done using

```
df.groupby(df.name.str.split().str[0]).foo_val.sum().reset_index()


    name        foo_val
0   Andrew      2
1   Braden      1
2   Cheryl      5
3   Christian   1
4   Derrick     4
```

Comment: that works perfectly! i had a sneaking suspicion that groupby might do the trick, guess i need to dive into that more! thank you!

Comment: Just a note. I was suspicious that there might be a lot of names that had spaces in them and did a search through nltk's names corpus... turns out there isn't many.

Comment: @Alter, I completely agree that solving this problem would entirely depend on the quality of the data. That is the reason I started with, in the example you posted above....